# xml string to arraylist and compare string to arralylist

Tags: c#, .net

I want to convert xml string to arraylist and check if specific string contains or not

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <SchoolStudent xmlns="http://service.webservice.123.school">
            <getDetailStudent xsi:type="ns1:masters" xmlns:ns1="http://brilliantstudent.123.test">
                <countries>India</countries>
                <dob/>
                <fullName>Schin Tendulkar</fullName>
            </getDetailStudent>
            <getDetailStudent xsi:type="ns2:masters" xmlns:ns2="http://brilliantstudent.123.test">
                <countries>Srilanka</countries>
                <dob/>
                <fullName>Murli Dharan</fullName>
            </getDetailStudent>
            
            <getDetailStudent xsi:type="ns3:masters" xmlns:ns3="http://brilliantstudent.123.test">
                <countries>Australia</countries>
                <dob/>
                <fullName>Ricky Ponting</fullName>
            </getDetailStudent>

            </SchoolStudent>
        </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: You should be more specific.
What the ArrayList should contains?
What strings are you searching for?

Comment: I am searching for Ricky Ponting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT per  `Jon Skeets'` recommendation with `XDocument` and `LINQ`:

```
if (XDocument.Parse(xml).Descendants().Where(node => node.Value == "Ricky Ponting").Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine("found Ricky Ponting");
}
```

Older `XmlDocument` API Based on the sample `XML` this can be accomplished with following `XmlNode` traversal:

```
var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xml);

var nodes = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("getDetailStudent");
foreach (XmlNode student in nodes)
{
    foreach (XmlNode prop in student.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (prop.Name == "fullName" && prop.InnerText == "Ricky Ponting")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Student Full Name: {prop.InnerText}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using LINQ to XML instead of the old `XmlDocument` API - it's a lot cleaner IMO.

Comment: @kshkarin Thank you so much. got what I really wanted